# Trying to loop a function to run on multiple elements - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get this jQuery parallax code to work but I don't want to spaghetti everything. How can it be looped to apply to multiple element IDs?

(it doesn't work with classes because the function needs to run multiple times specific to each particular div) - I'm not very good when it comes to looping, still learning how to do this stuff.

Anyway, this is a functioning code for one section (a div with a child div, #about > #pAbout in this instance):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#pAbout").length) {
    parallax();
  }
});

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  if ($("#pAbout").length) {
    parallax();
  }
});

function parallax(){
  if( $("#pAbout").length > 0 ) {
    var plxBackground = $("#pAbout");
    var plxWindow = $("#about");

    var plxWindowTopToPageTop = $(plxWindow).offset().top;
    var windowTopToPageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var plxWindowTopToWindowTop = plxWindowTopToPageTop - windowTopToPageTop;

    var plxBackgroundTopToPageTop = $(plxBackground).offset().top;
    var windowInnerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var plxBackgroundTopToWindowTop = plxBackgroundTopToPageTop - windowTopToPageTop;
    var plxBackgroundTopToWindowBottom = windowInnerHeight - plxBackgroundTopToWindowTop;
    var plxSpeed = 0.35;

    plxBackground.css('top', - (plxWindowTopToWindowTop * plxSpeed) + 'px');
  }
}
```

I was hoping to create an array like this:

```
var ids = ['#pAbout', '#pConcept', '#pBroadcast', '#pDigital', '#pDesign', '#pContact'];
```

But I can't get the e business to work unfortunately, it's very frustrating for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us your attempt at the loop please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple selector in jQuery to select disparate elements by simply using a comma between the selectors.

```
 $("#pAbout, #pConcept, #pBroadcast, #pDigital, #pDesign, #pContact")
    .each(function(){
     //manipulate element here
 });
```

That `each()` iterates over all matched elements so no need to check for length etc.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much - I'm going to try it tomorrow, I'll let you know how if it works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like this - I'm working it in so everything is self referencing within the .each function and I'm getting nothing back from it. I believe it's because they're all referencing the function name "parallax()" - just wondering if I can make that change with each iteration now..

Comment: it spaghettis just fine when i make new function names for each though, so i'm sure that's the problem..i'll start googling

Comment: You definitely have to change the  parallax function to use variable references rather than specific names. Inside the each function `$(this)` refers to the current matched element. Can you use that to work with it?

Comment: Yes - I am currently running my spaghetti version while I finish some other things with the intention of coming back to it, but I actually did use $(this) on my first attempt without success. The function name, parallax(), is referenced - I believe I have to make that name unique to each iteration - I'm going to try to google and see if there's a way to do that dynamically with each new iteration.